# How do I show the latest content from my SQL Database (mulitple tables) on my website?

Tags: sql, union

I have just started a website where I show pictures and video. On my FrontPage, I want the latest video/Picture to appear. I upload one Picture or Video each day, so all Pictures and Videos have different dates related to them in my databases.
I have two tables: "Pictures" and "Videos" with the same structure. 
The codes I use for fetching data from my databases look like this:

First two codes are the ones that show my Pictures or videos in a list.

```
$GET_picture = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Pictures ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1");
while($picture = mysql_fetch_array($GET_picture))
```

and

```
$GET_video = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Videos ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1");
while($video = mysql_fetch_array($GET_film)){
```

Next two codes are for showing a specific Picture or video:

```
$GET_spec_picture = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Pictures WHERE id='$id'");
$spec = mysql_fetch_array($GET_spec_picture);
```

and

```
$GET_spec_video = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE id='$id'");
$spec = mysql_fetch_array($GET_spec_video);
```

Again, what I want to do is to show the latest (and only the latest) Picture or video on my FrontPage.
I have tried using the UNION tag, but it did not Work. Could anyone show me how to use the tag correctly for this situation, or do I have another problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want both the latest video and picture? Or just latest between the the two?

Comment: Hi, I just want the latest between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP really is

```
if($_GET['mode'] == ""){ 
  $get_content = mysql_fetch_array("
     (SELECT * FROM Pictures
       ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1) 
     union all (SELECT * FROM Videos 
       ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1)
     order by Dato DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
   while($content = mysql_fetch_array($get_content)){...}
}
```

then you should replace the first `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysql_query`!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
(SELECT * FROM Pictures ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1)
union all
(SELECT * FROM Videos ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1)
order by Date desc
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

The `order by` in each subquery is, strictly speaking, unnecessary.  However, if you have an index on `date`, these will quickly get the most recent versions and the final sort on two rows is trivial.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, and thank for for the response. It was quite helpful.
However, it still does not fetch the latest content. At this pont, the code looks like this:

<?php
if($_GET['mode'] == ""){

$get_content = mysql_fetch_array("SELECT * FROM Pictures ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1)
union all
(SELECT * FROM Videos ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 0,1)
order by Dato DESC
LIMIT 0, 1;"
while($content = mysql_fetch_array($get_content)){
}
?>

Is it the quotation marks, or does is it because it does not understand "$content"?

Comment: - I am sincerely sorry about how the comment looks; I just cannot make it look more well-arranged.